# Get permission by default in AOSP project

Tags: android, permissions, android-source, custom-rom

I'm building a custom OS with my app as system app. I need to get storage, camera, etc., permissions by default when the OS is installed.

How can I get these permission by default without any user interaction?

Comment: Did you see: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-allowlist and https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/preinstalled-packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a xml file and Add the following lines (name the file as def_permission.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<exceptions>
    <exception package="com.<package_name>.<package>">
        <!-- <yourpackage> --> 
        <permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" fixed="false"/> 
        <permission name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" fixed="false"/> 
        <permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" fixed="false" /> 
        <permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" fixed="false" /> 
        <permission name="android.permission.CAMERA" fixed="false"/> 
        <permission name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" fixed="false" /> 
        <permission name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" fixed="false"/> 
        <permission name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" fixed="false"/> 
    </exception>
</exceptions>
```

for Android 9 and above --

copy def_permission.xml to device/make/model/def_permission.xml

add these following lines in device-model.mk , aosp_model.mk

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += device/make/model/def_permission.xml:product/etc/default-permissions/def_permission.xml
```

and build your custom rom , this will enable permissions for your apk by default